# Xcode fails to trigger ./gradlew script for KMM project in bigSur

Tags: xcode, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

This is my output when I try running my Xcode KMM project

```
jenv global -> openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
java -version -> {
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_212-b03)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.212-b03, mixed mode)
oracle64-11.0.10
}
echo $JAVA_HOME -> ***Nothing comes here***

./gradlew :shared:packForXCode -PXCODE_CONFIGURATION=${CONFIGURATION}

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/ch/AndroidStudioProjects/Test4001/androidApp/build.gradle.kts' line: 1

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
```

----<<<<>>>>-----
Anywhere in my Terminal:

```
java -version -> {
java version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.10+8-LTS-162)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.10+8-LTS-162, mixed mode)
}
jenv global -> oracle64-11.0.10

echo $JAVA_HOME -> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.10.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I would like to understand how and why Xcode could be picking up the wrong version, obviously besides the fact that it can't find JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this happens because xcode can't find the setup java version and gets some sort of default value.

If you would try to run your xcode project right now (I only reproduced this on BigSur) it will not work because the java version will show as outdated.

If you inspect with jenv or java you will find that your innner project folders and general version of java are setup correctly.

To fix this I just add an "export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v)" or "source ~/.zshrc" or "source ~/.bash_profile" before your run your scripts in Xcode

Of course the global version or your java_home must be in the correct java version you want to use

Answer (score 2):

I am facing similar issue earlier. It turns out you can edit the JAVA_HOME path from XCode.
XCode -> Settings -> Locations -> Custom Paths
and adding this :
JAVA_HOME | JAVA 19 | /Users/andrea/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-19.0.2/Contents/Home

It works after that